# How to call the Laravel Lang tool function in a controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed the tlr/laravel-lang-tools":v1.0.0 package in my project,I wanted to import and export Lang file using a controller in my application.Can any one give me an example for do it.

This package gives an Artisan command to export lang files in a csv file,The command is:

```
php artisan lang:export --format csv > translations
```

How can write my controller to do this with my routs

Comment: What is happening if you do Artisan::call('lang:export', ['--format' => 'csv > translations']) in your controller

Comment: The command Artisan::call('lang:export', ['--format' => 'csv' , 'translations']) ; work on controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a simple function export and side the method called the artsan command

```
public function export(){
    Artisan::call('lang:export', ['--format' => 'csv' , 'translations']) ;
    return Redirect::back();

}
```

This worked for me!